# How (if) are the Higgs scalar and the $W/Z$ vectors related (apart from interaction)?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

An idea popped up in my mind. There are three vector bosons, the two charged $W$-particles, and the $Z$-particle, all three with spin 1. Is the Higgs particle, having spin 0, related to them, apart from it giving them mass? The masses are the same order of magnitude. About 90GeV for the vector bosons, and about 130GeV for the Higgs.

Comment: Useful information:  https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/10/10/who-ate-the-higgs/

Comment: @Buzz *In fact, these three quarters of a Higgs live inside the belly of two beasts: the Z and W bosons!* The W and Z have eaten the Higgs? The three ate two Higgs?

Comment: The Higgs starts with four components.  Three of them are "eaten" and become the longitudinal states of the three massive gauge bosons.

Comment: @Buzz Which is why their mass is about 3/4 of Higgs?

Comment: No, as it states in Cosmas Zachos' answer, the masses are determined by the Higgs vacuum expectation value times the couple of the Higgs to each field (including its coupling to itself determining the Higgs mass).

Answer (score 2):

To the best of anybody's knowledge, the mass of the Higgs, $O(\sqrt{\lambda}v)$,  and the masses of the gauge bosons, $O(gv)$,  generated by the Higgs mechanism, are absolutely unrelated in the SM. Equivalently,

- *λ* and *g* are unrelated parameters in the Standard Model.

Before the discovery of the Higgs, debate was raging as to whether its mass was in the discovery capability range, and guess/"predictions" for its mass ranged from 1 order of magnitude below, to 1 above that of gauge bosons for over 3 decades.

*Indirectly*, near the end, people got to expect a mass in the neighborhood where it was discovered, but there is still incomplete understanding of its plausibility, in the absence of better understanding of the Higgs potential, currently under investigation.